# The system language of my application don't translate

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

The language system language of my application is displaying in english, for exemple when IOS ask me the autorization for geolocalisation, it's in english. Or the button "Done" on the right side of the keyboard is in english too. Problem is, it should be in French since this is my IOS language. It's only in IOS.

I know there is a way to translate them because I have an another Ionic application where this works, but I don't have the source code.

I guess it's somewhere in the xCode settings ?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286524/how-to-change-cordova-camera-plugin-language-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers was in [How to change cordova-camera-plugin language in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286524/how-to-change-cordova-camera-plugin-language-in-ios)

I needed to change the language here:

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>fr</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
      <string>nl</string>
    </array>
  <!-- other values omitted !-->
  </dict>
</plist>
```

But Im sure there is another way to do it, because this solution is not very good. It's only temporary, because if we delete the platform the change will be lost.

Comment: no, that's the only way right now. You can create a plugin or a hook to write that values on the info.plist again if the platform is deleted