# UIImagePickerController() to be same as app language while device language remain the same

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that support English and Malay. But I'm not using the localisation provided by Apple, instead I'm using a custom localisation that is declared in app itself to change the label text.

I have a function that will open image picker, which is `UIImagePickerController()`.

Is it possible to change the language that `UIImagePickerController()` uses to be the same as app language? (assume it is changed from English to Malay) Currently, since device language is English, when I open `UIImagePickerController(`), it will default to use device language.

The end product that I hopefully can achieve is if app language is Malay, the `UIImagePickerController` will use Malay, but the device language remain the same.

Any other possible solution that can possible achieve the same?

Comment: No, it is not possible to change system elements language from app

Comment: At best, you can localise `UIImagePickerController` with the device language like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258391/how-do-i-localize-uiimagepickercontroller . However, if you use any native iOS components out of your application, then the device language will be applied regardless what's the language of your application.